# Unity flip texture using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I call the method `FlipTextureVertically` in MakePhoto ?

My picture currently taken is upside down in unity, and I came across this texture flipping code, but I do not know how to apply it.

Would really appreciate if someone could help me out here!

```
public static Texture2D FlipTextureVertically(Texture2D original)
{
    Texture2D flipped = new Texture2D(original.width, original.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

    int xN = original.width;
    int yN = original.height;

    for (int i = 0; i < xN; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < yN; j++)
        {
            flipped.SetPixel(i, yN - j - 1, original.GetPixel(i, j));
        }
    }

    flipped.Apply();

    return flipped;
}

public string MakePhoto(bool openIt)
{          
    int resWidth = Screen.width;
    int resHeight = Screen.height;

    Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false); //Create new texture
    RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);        

    // hide the info-text, if any
    if (infoText) 
    {
        infoText.text = string.Empty;
    }
    // render background and foreground cameras
    if (backroundCamera && backroundCamera.enabled) 
    {
        backroundCamera.targetTexture = rt;
        backroundCamera.Render();
        backroundCamera.targetTexture = null;
    }

    if (backroundCamera2 && backroundCamera2.enabled) 
    {
        backroundCamera2.targetTexture = rt;
        backroundCamera2.Render();
        backroundCamera2.targetTexture = null;
    }

    if (foreroundCamera && foreroundCamera.enabled) 
    {
        foreroundCamera.targetTexture = rt;
        foreroundCamera.Render();
        foreroundCamera.targetTexture = null;
    }

    // get the screenshot
    RenderTexture prevActiveTex = RenderTexture.active;
    RenderTexture.active = rt;

    screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);

    // clean-up
    RenderTexture.active = prevActiveTex;
    Destroy(rt);

    byte[] btScreenShot = screenShot.EncodeToJPG();
    Destroy(screenShot);


    // save the screenshot as jpeg file
    string sDirName = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Screenshots";
    if (!Directory.Exists(sDirName))
        Directory.CreateDirectory (sDirName);

    string sFileName = sDirName + "/" + string.Format ("{0:F0}", Time.realtimeSinceStartup * 10f) + ".jpg";
    File.WriteAllBytes(sFileName, btScreenShot);

    Debug.Log("Photo saved to: " + sFileName);
    if (infoText) 
    {
        infoText.text = "Saved to: " + sFileName;
    }

    // open file
    if(openIt)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sFileName);
    }

    return sFileName;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really see why the screenshot should be upside down but I guess you should call it e.g. after

```
screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);

screenShot = FlipTextureVertically(screenShot);
```

but there might be more efficient ways of doing that.

---

E.g. not creating a new `Texture2D` but instead alter only the pixels in the one you already have like

```
public static void FlipTextureVertically(Texture2D original)
{
    var originalPixels = original.GetPixels();

    var newPixels = new Color[originalPixels.Length];

    var width = original.width;
    var rows = original.height;

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            newPixels[x + y * width] = originalPixels[x + (rows - y -1) * width];
        }
    }

    original.SetPixels(newPixels);
    original.Apply();
}

public static void FlipTextureHorizontally(Texture2D original)
{
    var originalPixels = original.GetPixels();

    var newPixels = new Color[originalPixels.Length];

    var width = original.width;
    var rows = original.height;

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            newPixels[x + y * width] = originalPixels[(width - x - 1) + y * width];
        }
    }

    original.SetPixels(newPixels);
    original.Apply();
}
```

and use it like

```
screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);

FlipTextureVertically(screenShot);
```

Comment: The screenshot currently taken is upside down by default. I am trying to fix that problem. And your help just did the trick for me. Once again thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) please check my update, altered the method so it manipulates the texture directly instead of creating a new one. Should be more efficient this way ;)

Comment: Can you show how to flip it horizontally as well, please? Thank you for the solution.

Comment: This is what I have made so far, but the texture is black and I cannot understand how to fix it: https://pastebin.com/UBYiFSBW

Comment: @Matthew I think my method but with `newPixels[x + y * width] = originalPixels[(width - x - 1) + y * width];` should do it ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, you are awesome! I was stuck for three hours >_<

Answer (score 0):

The reason your image is flipped is that you are swicthing the vertical pixels in your code.

```
public static Texture2D FlipTextureVertically(Texture2D original)
{
    Texture2D flipped = new Texture2D(original.width, original.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

    int xN = original.width;
    int yN = original.height;

    for (int i = 0; i < xN; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < yN; j++)
        {
            flipped.SetPixel(i, yN - j - 1, original.GetPixel(i, j));
        }
    }

    flipped.Apply();

    return flipped;
}
```

should be

```
public static Texture2D FlipTextureVertically(Texture2D original)
{
    Texture2D flipped = new Texture2D(original.width, original.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

    int xN = original.width;
    int yN = original.height;

    for (int i = 0; i < xN; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < yN; j++)
        {
            flipped.SetPixel(xN - i - 1, yN, original.GetPixel(i, j));
        }
    }

    flipped.Apply();

    return flipped;
}
```